# Strange behavior adding rules

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a checkout form and i configured jQuery Validate plugin to validate it.
For the credit card number and credit card cvc fields, i defined two new methods for the plugin:

```
$.validator.addMethod('creditCardNumber', function(value, element) {
    return adapter.checkNumber(value, element);
}, 'Tarjeta desconocida');

$.validator.addMethod('cardVerificationCode', function(value, element) {
    return adapter.checkCvc(value, element);
}, 'Cvc invalido');

// reference to ccn field
viewCache.$ccNumber.rules('add', {
   creditCardNumber: true
});

// reference to cvc field
viewCache.$ccCvc.rules('add', {
   cardVerificationCode: true
});
```

When i inspect the rules for both fields with:

```
    console.log(viewCache.$ccNumber.rules());
    console.log(viewCache.$ccCvc.rules());
```

The console shows:

> Object {required: true, creditCardNumber: true, cardVerificationCode:
>   true}
>
> Object {required: true, number: true, creditCardNumber: true, cardVerificationCode: true}

Why both fields has the creditCardNumber validator and the cardVerifiactionCode validator ?

The input references are right:

```
console.log(viewCache.$ccNumber.is(viewCache.$ccCvc)); // FALSE
console.log(viewCache.$ccNumber.length, viewCache.$ccCvc.lenght); // 1,1
```

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE 1**

The below code snippet shows how i created the viewCache.$ccNumber and viewCache.$ccCvc variables

```
var viewCache = {
   $ccNumber: $('[data-intellicard] [data-ccn]'),
   $ccCvc: $('[data-intellicard] [data-cvc]')
};
```

Comment: `viewCache.$ccNumber === viewCache.$ccCvc` will always be false - that doesn't mean the jQuery objects aren't pointing at the same element. How have you created those variables?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i updated my question, answering "How have you created those variables?"

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The ccn input and cvc input haven't got a name attribute (to prevent send their values to the server).

When add validators on the fly with jQuery Validation plugin, the plugin checks the name of the element to bind the added validator.

So, the full rules for my form was:

```
{
   // other rules
   ...
   // all rules for no name inputs
   '': {
      creditCardNumber: true,
      creditCardCvc: true
   }
}
```

This behavior is defined in staticRules plugin method.